# R script reporting wrong command line arguments

Tags: r, command-line-arguments

Apparently, in R, one can get args with the `commandArgs()` function.

Let's try. The file's name is `wtf.r`:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

args = commandArgs()

asdf = list()
asdf$arg1 = args[2] # Starting from 2 bc IIUC the first element is supposed to be the program's name
asdf$arg2 = args[3]
asdf$arg3 = args[4]

print(asdf)
```

Let's try running it:

```
my@comp:~/wtfdir$ ./wtf.r arg1 arg2 arg3
$arg1
[1] "--slave"

$arg2
[1] "--no-restore"

$arg3
[1] "--file=./wtf.r"
```

Wha..aat?!

Why is `arg1` set to `--slave`? Why is `arg2` set t0 `--no-restore`? Why is `arg3` set to `--file=./wtf.r`?! I don't remember entering anything of the sort in the command line!

What is going wrong in here?

Comment: You maybe want `commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)`?

Comment: @joran I'm surprised. Works. I thought it was a convenience option to ignore some of the *user supplied* args. ie I thought that if I invoked my script like `./wtf.r arg1 --args arg2 arg3` then `trailingOnly=TRUE` would ignore `arg1` and only report `arg2` and `arg3` while `trailingOnly=FALSE` would instead report all args. I was wrong, thank you